# Is there a neat/optimal method to read a constantly updated csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a very large csv (>5mm lines) that I have been testing with, but I am wondering if there is a neat way to convert it into a data frame. For testing, I am merely using pd.read_csv in juptyer so that I do not have to reload it each time, but in production the data will be constantly updated and there simply is not time to load the dataset.

How would I be able to go about updating the data frame as new data comes in? Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: How is your source CSV updated? Is it replaced completely? Or appended with new records at the end? Or may be some lines in between are updated? Depending on that an efficient solution can be derived.

Comment: Do you need to process the whole file each time or just new entries? Does the CSV have some kind of index? e.g. a number count or a timestamp entry?

Comment: @MartinEvans just new entries, and yes there is a timestamp for each entry.

Comment: @PankajSaini it is appended with new records at the end with fresh timestamps

Comment: I suggest you keep track of the file position and latest timestamp whilst reading in and save it to a file. Next time first seek to that location and locate the same time stamp before continuing

Comment: A better approach would be to either rename the file after processing (so it would start empty) or if possible add a timestamp to the filename when it is created

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Python's pandas doesn't provide any such features
but a Sample code could be:

```
import os
file = "filename.csv"
size = os.path.getsize("./"+file)
data = "";
def update_data():
     global data;
     new_size = os.path.getsize("./"+file)
     if new_size != size:
           data = pd.read_csv(file)
           size = new_size
update_data()
```

you have to call update_data in some intervals